# How to parse <yandex:full-text> tag in android xml pool parser

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I can parse following tags `(<item>, <title>)`, but I can't parse tag with namespace `(<yandex:full-text>)` namespace is,

```
xmlns:yandex="http://news.yandex.ru".
```

Who know how resolve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm try parse xml tag with namespace for example: [example](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/annotated-rss20-dc.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one.

**Sample XML data**

```
<current>
   <city id="2643743" name="London">
      <coord lon="-0.12574" lat="51.50853"/>
      <country>GB</country>
      <sun rise="2013-10-08T06:13:56" set="2013-10-08T17:21:45"/>
   </city>
   <temperature value="289.54" min="289.15" max="290.15" unit="kelvin"/>
   <humidity value="77" unit="%"/>
   <pressure value="1025" unit="hPa"/>
</country>
```

For here I'm asuming that you have input stream of your xml data.

```
InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

            XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

            myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES
            , false);
            myparser.setInput(stream, null);
            parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
            stream.close();
```

Above code sets XML data stream to PullParser and send to function parseXMLAndStoreIt().

**parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser)**

```
public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
      int event;
      String text=null;
      try {
         event = myParser.getEventType();
         while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name=myParser.getName();
            switch (event){
               case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
               break;
               case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
               text = myParser.getText();
               break;

               case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                  if(name.equals("country")){
                     country = text;
                  }
                  else if(name.equals("humidity")){     
                     humidity = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                  }
                  else if(name.equals("pressure")){
                     pressure = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                  }
                  else if(name.equals("temperature")){
                     temperature = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                  }
                  else{
                  }
                  break;
                  }      
                  event = myParser.next(); 

              }
                 parsingComplete = false;
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
```

Comment: This example parse a simple tags, need parse tag with namespace [example xml](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/annotated-rss20-dc.html)